# Unreal 4.24.3 : How to Declare UPROPERTY() inside .cpp file

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

What I want to do:

Create a USceneComponent at Runtime in an Actor class

```
    USceneComponent* UnitDesign = NewObject<USceneComponent>(this, FName(*ID));
```

What works:

Defining `UnitDesign` at Header File(.h) works without issues..

```
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)  //I can see UnitDesign in World Outliner
USceneComponent* UnitDesign = NewObject<USceneComponent>(this, FName(*ID));
```

What does not work for me:

Defining `UnitDesign` at CPP File(.cpp) inside BeginPlay() of Actor class-

```
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)  //I can NOT see UnitDesign in World Outliner
USceneComponent* UnitDesign = NewObject<USceneComponent>(this, FName(*ID));
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to create the UnitDesign SceneComponent then you can use `CreateDefaultSubobject` (c'tor only) :

```
/* .h */
UCLASS()
class AYourActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    AYourActor(FObjectInitializer const& ObjectInitializer);

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    USceneComponent* UnitDesign;
};

/* .cpp */
AYourActor::AYourActor(FObjectInitializer const& ObjectInitializer) :
    UnitDesign(nullptr) /* this is only needed if UnitDesign is not initialized below */
{
    UnitDesign = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Unit Design"));
}
```

If it's an optional thing then that's a bit more complicated, you can create a component later than the c'tor but you'll need to be a bit more conscious about when to get it to play nice with `VisibleAnywhere`. The code for that would just be

```
UnitDesign = NewObject<USceneComponent>(this, FName(*ID));
UnitDesign->RegisterComponent();
```

The sneaky way to refresh the property panel is to call :

```
GEditor->SelectActor(this, true, true);
GEditor->SelectNone(true, true);
```

The "proper" way is to call `SDetailsView::ForceRefresh` from a `IDetailCustomization`. Fair warning, it's a huge arse.

Side note that `UPROPERTY()` can only be used in a `.h` file as it needs to be visible to the Unreal Header Tool.